# using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with fopen() php

Tags: php, fopen

Background: I am using cPanel on my website and I have had problems with including files and such so I have gone to using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when doing includes.

Now I am trying to do stuff with `fopen()` and I am not getting the right files. (Also note that the files are in multiple folders; ex: `/euro/student/includes/file.xml`)

Is there a way I can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in my `fopen()` to get the file? If not, what would be the better way to get the file?

Comment: You're not getting the *right* files? What does that mean? What *do* you get instead? Also, some code would be helpful, because in most cases you don't really need to observe the document root.

Comment: Sorry. meant to say its not coming up with any files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with `fopen` like this:

```
$file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/euro/student/includes/file.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks. helped a lot. everything works great now

Answer (score 0):

You can use define function do define some constant vriables with paths

```
define("PATH", "/euro/students/incldes/");
```

and then use it like this

```
fopen(PATH."file.xml");
```